# Prove $\{1\}$ cannot be defined by any formula in structure $(R, +)$

Tags: first-order-logic

Consider the structure structure $(R, +)$ of real numbers for the language consisting of $∀, +$ (no multiplication nor constants). The addition operation is the usual operations. Prove that the set $\{1\}$ cannot be defined by any formula.  Could someone please give me some hints? Much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that $x\mapsto 2x$ is an isomorphism of structures to prove that if a formula defined $\{1\}$ then it would also define $\{2\}$.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you can try to prove by induction on formula structure that the only definable sets are {}, {$0$} , {$x : x != 0$} or $R$.

Comment: What about the set of non-zero reals?

Comment: yes, its the complement of {0}

Comment: Thank you very much. I accepted Oscar's answer because his answer solved my problem directly. Your answer gives me a lot of hints. Much appreciated.